# C Resizing BMP File by Factor of N, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, image, algorithm, resize

new to C.  Have been having troubles resizing a 24 bit uncompressed bitmap with my code.  I am trying to scale this image up by a factor of n, I feel that I am close to having it work properly but my outputted image is still not correct.

I can post pictures of the input 24 bit uncompressed BMP (small.bmp) I am using for testing, the picture my program is outputting (resized.bmp), and what the correct image of small.bmp scaled by a factor of 4 SHOULD look like, if that would be helpful.  Just ask.

***resize.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize scale infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file 
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);


    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }
    int oldpadding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    bi.biWidth = bi.biWidth * n;
    bi.biHeight = bi.biHeight * n;

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

bi.biSizeImage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth) + padding) * abs(bi.biHeight);
bf.bfSize = bi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);


    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(oldHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {

        // store scanline in an array pixel by pixel for vertical scaling.
        RGBTRIPLE scanline[bi.biWidth - 1];

        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            //check if we've hit padding in original bmp.
            if (j % oldpadding == 0 && j != 0) 
            {
                //skip the padding.
                fseek(inptr, oldpadding, SEEK_CUR);
            }

            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
            {
                //scale horizontally, save each scanline pixel to our array.
                scanline[j] = triple;
            }

        }

        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        {
            //write scanlines n - 1 times.
            for (int y = 0; y < bi.biWidth; y++)
            {
                    fwrite(&scanline[y], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }

            //write padding if any for current scanline.
            for (int z = 0; z < padding; z++)
            {
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
            }
        }

    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

***bmp.h***

```
/**
 * BMP-related data types based on Microsoft's own.
 */

#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Common Data Types 
 *
 * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++ 
 * primitive data types.
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
 */
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

/**
 * BITMAPFILEHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
 * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct 
{ 
    WORD bfType; 
    DWORD bfSize; 
    WORD bfReserved1; 
    WORD bfReserved2; 
    DWORD bfOffBits; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) 
BITMAPFILEHEADER; 

/**
 * BITMAPINFOHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure contains information about the 
 * dimensions and color format of a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    DWORD biSize; 
    LONG biWidth; 
    LONG biHeight; 
    WORD biPlanes; 
    WORD biBitCount; 
    DWORD biCompression; 
    DWORD biSizeImage; 
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD biClrUsed; 
    DWORD biClrImportant; 
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER; 

/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162939(v=vs.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: Removed some needless lines I had for testing.

Comment: [SO: this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861274/scaling-up-an-image-using-nearest-neighbor) seems to have the same mistake (although it's a little bit simpler). when scanning a line :`j < bi.biWidth` should be `j < bi.biWidth / n`. You should iterate on one image (in this case source) for both axes (not sure if there are more issues). Also: you're not checking function return codes for errors, also you're reading one triple at a time (inefficient), you could read (at least) one line.

Comment: @CristiFati Changed the conditional to what you mentioned, still not the correct ouput.  Effeciency < Correctness in this case also.  And checking function return codes is also beyond the scope of my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a mixture of two techniques for scaling: 1) scaling in an array and then writing it out, and 2) reading the array in it's original size and scaling while writing it out. However, your implementation of the first technique doesn't actually do any scaling:

```
for (int h = 0; h < n; h++)
{
    //scale horizontally, save each scanline pixel to our array.
    scanline[j] = triple;
}
```

Because you don't increment j, you're just overwriting the same triple to the same location n times. It doesn't do any scaling at all. I suggest abandoning the first technique and just focusing on the second. For starters, fix your array declaration:

```
RGBTRIPLE scanline[bi.biWidth];
```

Then when you read in, just write the triple to the correct location without any loop:

```
scanline[j] = triple;
```

When you write it out, you have the loops around the wrong way. You want to loop over the pixels and write each one out n times, not loop over the image n times and write out all the pixels (which will repeat the image n times rather than scaling it by n). Then wrap this all in a loop to output each row n times.

```
for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) // repeat each row n times
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bi.biWidth; x++) // iterate over pixels
    {
         for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) // repeat each pixel n times
             fwrite(&scanline[x], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
    }
    // write padding if any for current scanline.
    for (int z = 0; z < padding; z++)
    {
        fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }
}
```

This is the basic algorithm for scaling the image. You could improve the speed by doing block I/O reads and writes rather than calling fwrite in a loop but as you indicated in a comment, correctness > efficiency. You might also have some issues with padding, I haven't addressed that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I also caught the fact that I wasn't incrementing j, just a stupid thing I overlooked.  I guess you have to learn by failing sometimes :P